# Можно ли не дублировать предлог "из-за"?

Tags: предлоги

1. Игорь пошёл домой не из-за холода, а **из-за** страха.
2. Игорь пошёл домой не из-за холода, а страха.

Допустимо ли писать так же, как во втором варианте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, нельзя, потому что общее *"из-за"* тогда должно стоять перед *"не"*, а не после (иначе теряется его "общесть"): **Игорь пошёл домой из-за не холода, а страха**. Но такая конструкция стилистически неказиста, а нормальный вариант таков: **Игорь пошёл домой из-за страха, а не холода.** Однако здесь смысловое ударение смещается на *"холод"* со *"страха"*.